# How to set a this cart price rule?

Tags: shopping-cart-price-rules

If customer purchase more than and equal to 50. They can get specify SKU with qty 10 for free?

is it possible? I can define the condition. But for the Action, where I can insert the SKU and qty as for free gift?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Please check below Magento User Guide for `Marketing > Promotion > Cart Price Rules > Buy X Get Y Free`

> https://docs.magento.com/user-guide/marketing/price-rules-cart-buy-x-get-y-free.html

Or check this blog post with multiple examples of How to set up Buy X Get Y Free

> https://www.mageplaza.com/kb/how-setup-buy-x-get-y-free-in-magento-2.html

I hope this helps!

Comment: In condition, I can define total price if "total" >= $50, but I still have no idea where to define the Free "Y" by sku with 10 qty

Comment: For: Buy X get Y free (discount amount is Y) and for SKU > https://i.imgur.com/LtieSb2.png

Comment: I don't know why and where I can set the qty of the free Y?

Comment: In the "Discount Amount" field in Acton section.